# Flexbox Layout & Grid Layout make me make my html less semantic

Tags: html, css

I always have to make my HTML when working with flexbox layout and that is bad according to many people because you have to describe your structure with HTML and style your content with CSS. I have never worked with grid layout but I think it'll be the same.

Is it bad to make my HTML less semantic to be able to use flexbox layout and grid layout?

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <h1 class="name">Best City Guide</h1>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a class="realmains" href="#">ice cream</a></li>
    <li><a class="realmains" href="#">donuts</a></li>
    <li><a class="realmains" href="#">tea</a></li>
    <li><a class="realmains" href="#">coffee</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<!--/.main-header-->


VS


<header class="main-header">
  <h1 class="name">Best City Guide</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a class="realmains" href="#">ice cream</a></li>
      <li><a class="realmains" href="#">donuts</a></li>
      <li><a class="realmains" href="#">tea</a></li>
      <li><a class="realmains" href="#">coffee</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<!--/.main-header-->
```

Comment: so, what is this post about ? I am not sure there are going to be any answer which can be considered as solution.

Comment: I wanted to know if it was bad to not have tags such as <nav> to make your elements easier to style with flexbox

Comment: why not <nav class="main-nav">  ??

Comment: @vals i dont know i should have done that. I will change it right now. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a slight difference between your two examples.. The only difference is the nav tag. The difference really does not matter at all.